# how to save JUNG graph

Tags: java, jung

I am new to jung graph. I have implemented directed graph with my custom Vertex class. Now, I want to store  all the information in file. I have tried GraphMLWriter, but the problem is that graph vertices are the inherited classes from Vertex class. Is it possible to store all this vertex detail using GraphMLWriter?

```
public class Vertex{
   String name;
}

public class IfVertex extends Vertex{
   String condition;
}

public class CopyVertex extends Vertex{
   ArrayList<Copy> copyVars ;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can help you with this question but you'll have to be a bit more specific. What would you like your final output (the .graphml file) to look like?